# why do for loop does not work when I use increment operations for the arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, increment

I have two arrays in my code each one of them have 7 elements, I used a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    distance = x[++i] - x[i];
    area = trapezoidArea(distance, y[++i],y[i]);
    sum += area;
}
```

I wanted to calculate the area of a trapezoid. The difference of x[1]-x[0] will give me the height and y[1] is the first side, and y[0] is the second side.

This for loop doesn't work, and I want to know why.

Comment: Hint: `++` is not the same as `+ 1`.

Comment: Step through your program line by line (either mentally or with a debugger) and consider the values of your variables (especially `i`) every time.

Comment: You increase `i` three times in the loop. Are you sure you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `++` as post or pre-increment operator in this case. 
This will change the value of your `i` variable, and therefore your `for` loop won't have the behaviour you want. 
The proper way would be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    distance = x[i+1] - x[i];
    area = trapezoidArea(distance, y[i+1],y[i]);
    sum += area;
}
```

Be careful you have to loop until `i<6` because if you let 7, you'll try to access x[7+1] = x[8], and you'll have `undefined behaviour` or `segmentation fault`.

Answer (score 1):

`++i` increases `i`. So you increase `i` **thrice** in one run through the loop, and on top of that, it might also be undefined behavior because of sequencing. What's the `i` in `x[i]` supposed to be? The `i` before the `++i` in `x[++i]` increased it, or after it was increased?

If you want one more than `i` without increasing it, do `i+1` instead. Replacing `x[++i]` with `x[i+1]` and likewise with `y[++i]` should fix this issue. But without seeing all of your code, it's impossible to say if that's the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `++i` in the square brackets, you actually increment the value of `i` by one. What you should do is `i + 1` and leave `++i` only in the loop declaration.